# how to make sub-menu in drawer navigation marked when it's clicked?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, submenu

I have made a navigation drawer using this drawer_menu.xml, the codes are :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Home"></item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profil"
            android:title="Profile"></item>
    </group>
    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
                android:title="Message"></item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:title="Share"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

However, when I clicked the message menu item which is in sub-category, it's not marked instead it's only marked the item which isn't in sub-category. like the following :

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4gDG.png)

I would be glad if someone could help this :) thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have , `3 items` with 3rd items(communicate) will have `sub items` , so you need to add  `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` under that sub-item  ,also you have  close your  tag with 2 items only(home,profile) ,you didn't include 3rd item .try closing it at end ,like i have done in below code :

```
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Home"></item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profil"
            android:title="Profile"></item>


<item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
              <group android:checkableBehavior="single">//selecting one item from group
            <item
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
                android:title="Message"></item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:title="Share"></item>
              </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>//add this
```

Comment: it's worked :) why the first group tag should closed at 3rd item? as "communicate" isn't used for checkableBehavior.